# ASP.NET 4.0 Rewrite Rules in Global.aspx File Issues with rewrite

Tags: url-rewriting

I have a rewrite rule I'm using in ASP.NET 4.0 on IIS7:

```
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Rewrite default to aspx" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^$" ignoreCase="false" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="home.aspx" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
<defaultDocument>
  <files>
    <add value="home.aspx" />
  </files>
</defaultDocument>
</system.webServer>
```

This rule takes: (http:/example.com/aboutus.aspx) and it removes the .aspx from the end of the URL. I'm running into problems with wordpress being installed on my subdomain (http:/www.example.com/blog) I get the following error due to my rewrite rule:

> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /blog/.aspx

Does anyone know how I can fix the URL rewrite rule so it safely get to (http://www.example.com/blog/) and not add the .aspx at the end?

Is there some sort of syntax that can search for the blog subdirectory to ignore the directory '/blog/'?

Greatly appreciated! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want your rule to be applied to every urls but the `/blog/*` ones, then you can use the negate option:

```
<rule name="Rewrite default to aspx" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^blog/" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="home.aspx" />
</rule>
```

http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference#Rule_pattern_properties